# StackTrace inside an Exception in .Net Xamarin

Tags: .net, xamarin, exception, servicestack

Inside my .Net Xamarin app, I don't get a stack trace with this code:

```
new Exception().StackTrace
```

Why not, and how can I get it?

**Update:**

If I call the following code, I get a `stackTrace` with one frame only:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var stackTrace = e.StackTrace;
}
```

So, throwing the exception is not a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to get here, StackTrace of what?

Comment: I have Logger inside my app, which logs the exceptions. For uncaught exceptions, it shows me the uncaught exception handler location only. But not the point, where the exception happened. Right now, I have object not initialized (null) exception, but no idea, where in my code this occurred.

Comment: In general, we can find the relative error by class `Exception`. If you have problem in your app, you can share the error here so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The `StackTrace` property of an exception is only populated when the exception is thrown. If you want to get the stack trace of the current execution point, you can use `Environment.StackTrace`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not show the stack trace to me too.